# Ordered pairs of Integers $(x,y)$ which satisfy $x!\cdot y! = x!+y!+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the total number of ordered pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ which satisfy
>
> $$
> \tag1 x!y! = x!+y!+2
> $$

**My Attempt:**

We can write $(1)$ as

$$
\begin{align}
x!y!-x!-y!+1 &= 3\\
\left(x!-1\right)\left(y!-1\right) &= 3=1\times 3 = 3\times 1
\end{align}
$$

So, without loss of generality, $(x!-1)=1$ and $(y!-1)=3$, which implies that  $x!=2$ and $y!=4$. But there is no $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $y!=4$. Thus no ordered pairs $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z^2}$ exist which satisfy the given equation.

Is this solution correct? If not, why not?

Comment: Your solution is fine, based on the fact that $3$ is prime (which you may want to mention). Alternatively, one might first solve $ab=a+b+2$ for integers $a,b$ and then notice that none of the solutions $(2,4)$, $(4,2)$, $(0,-2)$, $(-2,0)$ looks like a pair of factorials ...

Comment: It seems valid to me. You could remark that $(x!-1)=1$ or $3$ because $(x!-1)$ is always an integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems correct.

Another way to prove this might be to say that your original equation implies $x!y!-x!-y!=2$ and that if wlog $x \leq y$, then the left side is divisible by $x!$ (because the three terms are) while the right side (2) is only divisible by $x!$ if $x=1$ or $x=2$ which both easily lead to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof:

Assume $x\geq y\geq 3$. Then we have $$x!\,y!\geq x!\,3!>3\cdot x!=x!+x!+x!>x!+y!+2$$ The cases $0<x,y<3$ are checked by hand.

Comment: Yes, as long as you check remaining cases as well (look at last sentence)